# Asp.net MVC BreadCrumb

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to implement BreadCrumb in my Asp.net MVC project .

I don't have any experience in Asp.net. I have tried reading past questions but I could not really undrestand them.

I have tried to undrestand MvcSiteMap Project Description in codeplex but It is not like a step by step tutorial .

for example in Creating a first sitemap section ,it says that this is the first xml which can be used with the MvcSiteMapProvider but I don't know really where should I put this Xml file.

can you please tell me where can I find simple and step by step tutorial

Regards

Answer (score 0):

try it.

http://geekswithblogs.net/Patware/archive/2008/11/12/126987.aspx